# SSRS 2008 - Put an empty table in the footer

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

Here is essentially what I am trying to have...I would like an empty table (with 5 or so blank rows) always at the bottom of my report. I have a different table in the body of my report, so if that gets too big, I would like it (the body table) to automatically go to the next page so that it doesnt push down my empty table (again, I want it always on the bottom).

Currently I have a picture of the table and placed that into the footer but that is a bare to maintain because of column changes. I was curious if there was an easier way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure you ran into the issue where you can't have a table/subreport, etc in a footer.

Have you considered a series of adjacent textboxes in the footer to mimic the look of a table? Still a pain to maintain but much easier than an image - at least this way it's all in the same report and you can edit it all in the same place.

[image]

Comment: Works but when I export to Excel, they show real goofy.The columns are basically just listed vertical and dont have their border colors.